# How do I $n\lambda ^n$ tends to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

I'm working with sequences of functions, and I have a question about a limit:
If $$0<\lambda <1$$
then, when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $n$ natural number,
$$(n\lambda ^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow 0\, \, ?$$

How can I prove it? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Is $\;\{n\lambda^n\}\;$ the fractional part of $\;n\lambda^n\;$ ? And do you know about series?

Comment: Yes: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\lambda^x}{\frac{1}{x}}$ gives me the indetermination "$0$/$0$" and I need to see the behaviour of $$\frac{ln(\lambda ) \lambda^x}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: Try the other way up?

Comment: @Mario, no me contestaste: ¿ya has estudiado series infinitas?

Comment: @MarioDeLeónUrbina : Could you write $\ln(\lambda)$ instead of $ln(\lambda)$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: We seem to hit some variation of this same question every day.  Fortunately this time it's phrase in a notation that suggests the variable is an integer --- i.e. just calling it "$n$" suggests that.  The fortunate result is that no one's used L'Hopital's rule in the posted answers, the way they did the last six times or so over the past week.  L'Hopital's rule is sometimes beautifully efficient in giving the right answer, but it gives no insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using infinite series:

$$a_n:=n\lambda^n\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}n\lambda\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\lambda<1$$

and thus by the ratio test (D'Alembert's Test) , the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\lambda^n\;\;\text{converges}\;\implies\;n\lambda^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Answer (score 5):

A plain old pre-calculus series and sequences demonstration:

For $0 < \lambda < 1$, we have $1 < \lambda^{-1}$ whence $0 < \lambda^{-1} - 1$.  Thus there exists a positive $N$ such that $0 < N^{-1} < \lambda^{-1} - 1$; then $1 + N^{-1} < \lambda^{-1}$; multiplying this inequality through by $N\lambda$ yields $(N + 1)\lambda < N$ or $((N + 1)/N)\lambda < 1$; this last may be written $(1 + (1/N))\lambda < 1$.  Taking integer $n \ge N$ shows that $(1 + (1/n))\lambda \le (1 + (1/N)) \lambda < 1$ or $((n + 1)/n)\lambda \le (1 + (1/N)) \lambda < 1$ for all such $n$.  Thus there exists $\rho$, $0 < \rho < 1$, with $(1 + (1/N))\lambda < \rho < 1$ and

$\dfrac{(n + 1) \lambda^{n + 1}}{n \lambda^n} = \dfrac{(n + 1) \lambda}{n} \dfrac{\lambda^n}{\lambda^n} = \dfrac{(n + 1)\lambda}{n} \le (1 + (1/N))\lambda < \rho < 1, \tag{1}$

under the *proviso* that $n \ge N$.  Thus,

$(n + 1)\lambda^{n + 1} < \rho (n \lambda^n) \tag{2}$

for all $n \ge N$ sufficiently large.  But then

$(n + 2)\lambda^{n + 2} < \rho ((n + 1) \lambda^{n + 1})  < \rho^2 (n \lambda^n), \tag{3}$

and it is pretty easy to see that continuing in this manner leads to

$(n + m)\lambda^{n + m} < \rho^m (n\lambda^n) \to 0 \; \text{as} \; m \to \infty. \tag{4}$

(2) and (4) show that once the sequence $n \lambda^n$ progresses to the point where $n \ge N$, it decreases monotonically to zero as $n \to \infty$.  ***QED.***

And that's how it may be shown!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 2):

Instead of $$\frac{\lambda^x}{1/x}$$
use $$\frac{x}{\lambda^{-x}}$$
in L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: I was thinking about this expression in this form today with a friend. Thanks :)